# How can I execute commands as another user with their .bash_profile instead of the current user's?

Tags: linux, sudo, init, su, bash

I want to run a command as a not-root user in a startup script (rc.local). The command I want to execute is actually an alias in the non-root user's .bash_profile. I have tried to use

```
su - myuser -c aliased_cmd
```

but this doesn't work. If I simply type

```
su - myuser
# wait for login...
aliased_cmd
```

it works fine, but obviously this isn't appropriate in the actual script. Of course I could copy the aliases and functions I'd like to use into the actual rc.local file, but this seems a bit silly... perhaps there is an option I don't know about or a way to use sudo for this?

Comment: have you tried to execute 'source /path-to-non-root-user-home-dir/.bash_profile' before executing the alias command?

Comment: this was a good idea, and actually the fact that this doesn't work perhaps points to issue somehow? this seems like it definitely _should_ work: su - myuser -c "source .bash_profile; aliased_cmd"

Comment: Have you tried `--preserve-environment` or `su -c 'echo "$SHELL"' myuser`? It might be that the command is not executed in a Bash shell.

Comment: Definitely bash, and running su - myuser -c "cat .bash_profile" confirms it's the right one...

Comment: As an experiment, I added an echo to my .bash_profile to be sure it was being run. It was, but my alias still wasn't working, so I tried calling a function instead, which did work. Problem solved I suppose - don't use aliases? Anyone have any idea why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after sourcing the profile, include the following

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

Comment: just adding this line to the .bash_profile does the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting `man su`:

> When - is used, it must be specified as the last su option.

It doesn't specify what happens if it's not the last option. Also, in the synopsis the username is *after* all the options.

Have you tried `su -c aliased_cmd - myuser` or `su -l -c aliased_cmd myuser`?